# Postman request not loading node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am a newbie at `node.js`. Trying to learn from [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDrU305J1yw)

It was perfectly working fine few minutes ago. Not sure what happened. There is no error on command. Suddenly it stopped loading at postman.

It was perfectly working fine with `localhost:3000/orders` that displayed the message `message: 'Order was created',` Now it stopped working for no reason. I can't debug since i am not able to see any error.

[image: no error]

It hangs right here.
[image]

This is a orders.js route. I am having a custom message for each request it get.
`orders.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router =  express.Router() ;

router.get('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Orders were fetched'
    });
});

router.post('/', (req,res,next)=>{
    const order = {
        productId : req.body.productId,
        quantity: req.body.quantity
    }
    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Order was created',
        order: order
    });
});

router.get('/:orderId', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Order details',
        orderId: req.params.orderId
    });
});

router.delete('/:orderId', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Order deleted',
        orderId: req.params.orderId
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products');
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/orders');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://**************@cssmania-shard-00-00-zfebp.mongodb.net:27017,cssmania-shard-00-01-zfebp.mongodb.net:27017,cssmania-shard-00-02-zfebp.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=cssmania-shard-0&authSource=admin');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if(req.method==='OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT, POST,PATCH,DELETE');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }

})

app.use('/products', productRoutes); 
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes); 

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    const error = new Error('Not found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

app.use((error, req,res,next)=>{
    res.status(error.status || 500)
    res.json({
        error: {
            message: error.message
        }
    })
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: I believe you should call next() on your first middleware

Comment: can you plz point exactly where ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `next()` in your middleware so the request can continue.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    if(req.method==='OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT, POST,PATCH,DELETE');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next(); // Right here
});
```

You can read more about middlewares in the [Express Docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Comment: No problem! Please mark it as the answer to help other users find it more easily! Thanks